# How i can set magento promotions with defined hours?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, promotions, cart-rule

Is there a way to defined hours with each promotion in `magento` so that `promotion` will be active only in that specified `hours`.

Also how we can active time with date in special prices date in magento product edit page.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of extensions you could use

[promotional offers](https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/promotional-offers.html)

[promotional schedule](https://github.com/alvinnguyen/promotionschedule)